# what does same email occuring multiple times in postfix maillog mean?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, email-server

we use third party email sending software to send email using postfix mailserver. today i saw strange thing in postfix maillog as below:-

```
 #grep "bkinnaman@gmail.com" /var/log/maillog
Oct  4 12:56:14 server postfix/smtp[165030]: 92EBD21B4436: to=<bkinnaman@gmail.com>, relay=us-smtp-inbound-1.mimecast.com[205.139.110.141]:25, delay=10, delays=0.1/0/2.7/7.5, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 SmtpThread-29149994-1507136156344@us-mta-112.us.mimecast.lan Received OK)
Oct  4 12:56:14 server postfix/smtp[165030]: 92EBD21B4436: to=<bkinnaman@gmail.com>, relay=us-smtp-inbound-1.mimecast.com[205.139.110.141]:25, delay=10, delays=0.1/0/2.7/7.5, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 SmtpThread-29149994-1507136156344@us-mta-112.us.mimecast.lan Received OK)
```

does this mean that the email is sent twice to the email "bkinnaman@gmail.com" ?

Answer (score 1):

These two messages belong to one mail that has been sent once. `92EBD21B4436` indicates a message id that is unique to your server and some part of `SmtpThread-29149994-1507136156344` is the unique message id on the receivers side.

The double message might arise from a log misconfiguration - but that's pure guessing.